# Convert string into fixed length numbers and convert it back

Tags: string, algorithm, encryption, numbers, decimal

I have more than 100 cpp files. I need to assign unique ID to each of them. I aslo need to know which file it is based on their ID. I found the maximum length of file's name contains 64 characters and the ID can only be at most 8 bytes long. Is there any algorithm can help to assign unique ID to source file in VS2013 in C++ and can also let user know which file it is based on the ID ?

Just store a mapping between filename and an integer.
-----Yes, this way is very simple. But every time when people create new course files, the mapping need to be re-coded. So I won't use this way.

**HERE IS THE ORIGINAL QUESTION SO THAT THE COMMENTS BELOW MAKE SENSE**

Now I have a bunch of strings, like "AAA", or "ABBCCHH". The maximum of string contains 64 characters. Now I need an algorithm which can convert string into numbers( not must be integer, double float is also acceptable). But the length of numbers must be fixed. For example, if "A" is convert into 12312, 5 digits, "ABBHGGH" should also have 5 digits after converted. And these numbers can also be converted back to original strings. Is there any algorithms can do that ? The converted number cannot over 8 bytes. That's why I cannot just use ASCII etc simple algorithm. I don't know which algorithm can do that.

Comment: Yes there is. What have you tried?

Comment: I didn't find any of that. I know sha1 ca convert into fixed number, but it occupies to many bytes.

Comment: How do you determine the length of the number? Your input character set is undefined (ASCII, UTF-8, just uppercase letters, etc.), but even taking the most conservative approach, you have `(26^64)+(26^63)+...+(26)` possible input strings, which is a number with the exponent `90`. You're going to need a large number to encode all of the possible outputs.

Comment: Perhaps design your own algorithm

Comment: @andy - It does not mention that two strings cannot have the same number. Perhaps the length of the string irrespective of the characters fits the criteria

Comment: If two different strings have same number, how could I convert numbers into original strings ?

Comment: @Andy How do you determine the length of the number?--- Not me, that's the requirement. That's why I post the question here. I know some algorithm like sha1 can do that, but it is not what I need.

Comment: My point is that if "For example, if "A" is convert into 12312, 5 digits, "ABBHGGH" should also have 5 digits after converted." is true, the output space is probably not large enough. Even with 1-7 capital letters only, that's 8353082582 combinations. So a 5 digit number would not be able to express the entire output space.

Comment: I don't know where you got this homework assignment from, but it's missing information. As Ed said, yes, algorithms exist to encode arbitrary data into numerical representation, but you haven't provided enough information to help you.

Comment: The maximum length of number is 8 bytes, but the maximum length of string contains 64 characters. I understand what you are worrying about, so that's why I post the question here to see is there any way that can convert all strings no matter it is long or not to fixed length numbers !!!!!

Comment: Are you sure the question is not how to encode arbitrary 8 bit values (i.e. a byte) numerically and reversibly? I think you are looking for a *character encoding*. You say you cannot use ASCII because it doesn't handle 8 byte values. What about [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)?

Comment: @Andy - I am not sure that the poster knows what (s)he wants. I think the question needs to be thought about and re-written

Comment: The real problem is, I have more than 100 cpp files, I need to assign unique ID to each of them. I can also get the file name based on the ID. I don't want just simply assign ID based on their order.

Comment: Lack of correct terminology makes this question very difficult to interpret...

Comment: If your question truly is "can I reversibly encode an arbitrary string of length 1 - 64 into a set of numbers of fixed length?" the answer is "yes, provided the set of numbers contains `sum_(n=1)^64 26^(65 - n) = 3761210236658468968779943965923267719905413971532938537226100308986137155150040411245945814` values.

Comment: @firstaccount - Just store a mapping between filename and an integer.

Comment: Just store a mapping between filename and an integer.---- It is the most time wasting solution.

Comment: Why is it time wasting

Comment: Yes, this way is very simple. But every time when people create new course files, the mapping need to be re-coded.

Comment: "But every time when people create new course files, the mapping need to be re-coded" -- you've said this multiple times. I don't understand what this means. I think you are describing multiple people storing their files in a common directory, but why would the "mapping" get "re-coded" (?) when new files come in? Just assign the next available number to each file as it comes in. Are you afraid you will run out of numbers?

Comment: Never mind, thanks for pay attention to that. I will figure it out by myself.

Comment: @firstaccount - Please do not re-write the post - the comments stop making sense to new people viewing the thead

Answer (score 1):

To generate unique IDs of an arbitrary set of filenames (the actual question here), you could use a cryptographic hash (SHA-1, -256, -384, -512). This will result in a unique, fixed-length hexadecimal output. If you can't allow the characters `a-f` in the output, you can convert the hexadecimal value to decimal.

This process is not reversible, but you can maintain a map (lookup table) of the input values to the IDs.

If you want a simpler solution, just hexadecimal encode the filenames. This is reversible. (You can add the hex -> decimal conversion here if necessary as well).

Comment: If you are going to store a mapping (i.e. convert number->filename), why bother with SHA etc. Just store the next unused id number. When a new file name comes along assign it to that value

Comment: Also the poster took 32 minutes to partially describe the real problem

Comment: @EdHeal, I agree that the sequential assignment is simplest, but the OP specifically said they did not want to assign the number based on order (why, I don't know).

Comment: I already said in comment that SHA doesn't fit my requirement. And if I need a map to store for SHA, I even don't need SHA.

Comment: If SHA-1 occupies too many bytes, truncate it at whatever length boundary you want. You've changed the requirements many times. If you don't want a map, just use the encoding and truncate that. But be aware that you could have collisions if the truncated segment of the filenames are not unique.